# How do I create a transparent .png in SUMO Paint?

Tags: image-manipulation, sumo-paint

I find SUMO Paint great for doing quick and dirty edits of photographs when I don't have anything else available, and I was hoping I could create a .png file with a transparent background for iPhone app tab bar images, but can't figure it out.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create new image
2. Add a new Layer
3. Delete the initial Background layer

[image]

And now you have a transparent image.